# Saving div to canvas to image (jpeg) and auto save in server

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, save, html2canvas

HTML:
`<div id='mydiv' name='mydiv' width='600' height='600' >
<img src="clouds.png"></div>`

```
$(document).ready(function () 
     {
        //alert("save pleaseeeee?");

        $("#save").click(function () 
        {
          html2canvas([document.getElementById('mydiv')],
          {
            onrendered: function (canvas) 
            {
              var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
              $.post("save.php", 
              {
                data: canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")
              }, 

              function (file) 
              {
                window.location.href =  "download.php?path="+ file
              });
            })
        });
        // end of onclick save
     });
```

The autosave works when converting a canvas to image only. I tried to merge it with the html2canvas function so that I can save div-canvas-image. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the canvas element html2canvas is providing. Try to use that argument directly:

```
onrendered: function (canvas) // <- use this argument
{
  /// This is overwriting the rendered canvas
  //var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  $.post("save.php", 
  {
    data: canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")
  }, 

  function (file) 
  {
    window.location.href =  "download.php?path="+ file
  });
})
```

From the [documentation](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html):

> The rendered canvas is provided in the callback event onrendered, as
>   such:
>
> ```
> html2canvas(element, {
>     onrendered: function(canvas) {
>         // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
>     }
> });
> ```